# How to do text calculations using columns in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to conditionally include the values from particular columns in a SQL query. To illustrate the question let me use the fictional example of returning selective data about users.

If we were to return all data we'd use a query of the form:

```sql
SELECT 
  name, email, gender 
FROM 
  users
```

Assume all users have entered their gender. However some have set the value of `gender_public` to be false and I would like to reflect this in the data the query returns.

The type of thing I'd like to do is:

```sql
SELECT 
  name, email, if(gender_public, gender, 'N/A')
FROM 
  users
```

Is this possible? I'm working with Postgres

Comment: You are looking for a `CASE` expression

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted - thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using CASE

This is the obvious way to go, as suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name.

Assuming gender_public is of type BOOLEAN.

```
SELECT name, email, CASE WHEN gender_public THEN gender ELSE 'N/A' END AS gender
FROM users;
```

### Using lateral join

This way of doing is especially useful if you need to use the value in more than one place and want to remain consistent.

```
SELECT name, email, T.gender
FROM users
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT gender WHERE show_gender
  UNION
  SELECT 'N/A' WHERE NOT(show_gender)
) T(gender)
```

Comment: The `bit` stuff looks strange. I would assume `gender_public` is a `boolean` column. `CASE WHEN gender_public THEN ...` would seem a better choice.

Comment: Indeed, let me update my answer. Thank you for your piece of advice! :-)